# Filling DS-160 for B1 visa as single, but getting married in a week

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas

I need to fill the DS-160 ASAP for a B1 visa, so I cannot really wait for this. However, I am getting married in a week, which means that during the interview I'll most probably be married. I was wondering whether that could reflect badly in any way during my interview.

The spouse is a citizen of my country, so I'm not marrying a US citizen for what it's worth.

How do you suggest I should proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was wondering whether that could reflect badly in any way during my interview.

There's no reason for it to reflect badly.

> How do you suggest I should proceed?

Submit the application with your status as "single."  If there is any place to make additional comments, note your planned wedding date.  At your interview, tell the interviewer about your change in circumstances.